# Android ViewPager get the current View

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs, android-viewpager

I have a ViewPager, and I'd like to get the current selected and visible view, not a position.

1. `getChildAt(getCurrentItem)` returns wrong `View`
2. This works not all the time. Sometimes returns null, sometimes just returns wrong View.

   ```
   @Override
   public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
       super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);

       if (isVisibleToUser == true) { 
           mFocusedListView = ListView; 
       }
   }
   ```
3. PageListener on `ViewPager` with `getChildAt()` also not working, not giving me the correct View every time.

How can i get current visible View?

```
View view = MyActivity.mViewPager.getChildAt(MyActivity.mViewPager.getCurrentItem()).getRootView();
ListView listview = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.ListViewItems);
```

Answer (score 140, accepted):

I've figured it out. What I did was to call `setTag()` with a name to all `View`s/`ListView`s, and just call `findViewWithTag(mytag)`, `mytag` being the tag.

Unfortunately, there's no other way to solve this.

Comment: I can't believe this is the best option but it works. I am just setting the index as the tag when the adapter creates the item.

Comment: +1 to the absurdity of this solution, but it is definitely the best. Using the position as the tag in PagerAdapter.instantiateView and retrieving the View with findViewBy(getCurrentItem()) is the most elegant form of this hack.

Comment: another +1 @lacas for finding this solution

Comment: I didnt completely understand it.

Comment: @usman for example imageView.setTag(R.string.firstname, "Abhishek");
You have to use application-specific resource id, otherwise there's an error https://stackoverflow.com/q/2859574/1645641

Comment: Please tell me there's a better way to do this almost six years later!?

Comment: Where do I set the tag?
This is driving me crazy

Comment: @JoelBroström A place where you inflating a view and returning it, it will be in your pager adapter if using simple adapter or it will will be in `onCreateView` of a fragment if you are using fragment pager adapter

Comment: @GraphTheory, The correct way to do this is by overrideing the `onViewAttachedToWindow(holder: Holder)` method in adapter class (extension of RecyclerView.Adapter). (my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76838280/7835969)

Comment: Could you show a code example please? Or could one of the commentators post an answer?

Answer (score 10):

I just came across the same issue and resolved it by using:

```
View view = MyActivity.mViewPager.getFocusedChild();
```

Comment: This wont always work, sometimes focus is elsewhere even tho a view from ViewPager is currently displayed

Comment: That may be so, but works if you request focus on the page that gets visible

Comment: Unless, im misunderstanding something here. What do you mean specifically by "request focus"? Because if i do `mViewPager.getChildAt(i).isFocused()` for all children, it reports `false` for all children. Which is probably because I'm putting this code into the options menu which is a part of the MainActivity, thus moving focus from the ViewPager. Therefore, this way wont work in certain situations.

Comment: yes, this might be a dialog popup or a Toast object. So use method isVisible() instead

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for AndroidX ViewPager 1.0.0/Support library ViewPager 28.0.0

Answer (score 10):

I use this method with `android.support.v4.view.ViewPager`

```
View getCurrentView(ViewPager viewPager) {
        try {
            final int currentItem = viewPager.getCurrentItem();
            for (int i = 0; i < viewPager.getChildCount(); i++) {
                final View child = viewPager.getChildAt(i);
                final ViewPager.LayoutParams layoutParams = (ViewPager.LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();

                Field f = layoutParams.getClass().getDeclaredField("position"); //NoSuchFieldException
                f.setAccessible(true);
                int position = (Integer) f.get(layoutParams); //IllegalAccessException

                if (!layoutParams.isDecor && currentItem == position) {
                    return child;
                }
            }
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It's exactly what I want

Answer (score 8):

You can get the current element by accessing your list of itens from your adapter calling `myAdapter.yourListItens.get(myViewPager.getCurrentItem());`
As you can see, ViewPager can retrieve the current index of element of you adapter (current page).

If you is using FragmentPagerAdapter you can do this cast:

```
FragmentPagerAdapter adapter = (FragmentPagerAdapter)myViewPager.getAdapter();
```

and call

```
adapter.getItem(myViewPager.getCurrentItem());
```

This works very well for me ;)

Comment: Works only in case your adapter is FragmentPagerAdapter

Comment: Note that `getItem()` is supposed to always return a new instance of a Fragment when subclassing `Fragment(State)PagerAdapter`. Therefore, this isn't right insofar as it just creates a new instance instead of returning the "old" one.

Comment: The above comment is wrong.  Directly from the docs: "Return the Fragment associated with a specified position." Says nothing about returning a new Fragment.

Comment: Your answer returns the Fragment, but for me, the Fragment is empty.  adapter.getItem(myViewPager.getCurrentItem()).getView() returns null.

Answer (score 2):

During my endeavors to find a way to decorate android views I think I defined alternative solution for th OP's problem that I have documented in [my blog](http://bstrandjev.blogspot.co.uk/2014/12/the-missing-viewpager-getcurrentview.html). I am linking to it as the code seems to be a little bit too much for including everything here.

The solution I propose:

- keeps the adapter and the view entirely separated
- one can easily query for a view with any index form the view pager and he will be returned either `null` if this view is currently not loaded or the corresponding view.

Answer (score 2):

Use an Adapter extending PagerAdapter, and override setPrimaryItem method inside your PagerAdapter.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerAdapter.html

```
class yourPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter
{
    // .......

    @Override
    public void setPrimaryItem (ViewGroup container, int position, Object object)
    {
        int currentItemOnScreenPosition = position;
        View onScreenView = getChildAt(position);
    }

    // .......

}
```

Comment: Doesn't answer the original question to get the actual view. Also, if you wanted the position why not use [getCurrentItem()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager)?

Comment: Yes. I forgot to write that to get the view you just have to use: getChildAt(currentItemOnScreenPosition).

Comment: On the other hand, the getCurrentItem() function doesn't return the current selected and visible view, as the original question says, _getChildAt(getCurrentItem)_ returns wrong View. I think the getCurrentItem() function returns the item that is currently computed by the viewPager, and this item may not be the same that is currently on screen

Answer (score 2):

```
viewpager.getChildAt(0)
```

this always returns my currently selected view. this worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not have many pages and you can safely apply `setOffscreenPageLimit(N-1)`
where N is the total number of pages without wasting too much memory then you could do the following:

```
public Object instantiateItem(final ViewGroup container, final int position) {      
    CustomHomeView RL = new CustomHomeView(context);
    if (position==0){
        container.setId(R.id.home_container);} ...rest of code
```

then here is code to access your page

```
((ViewGroup)pager.findViewById(R.id.home_container)).getChildAt(pager.getCurrentItem()).setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
```

If you want you can set up a method for accessing a page

```
RelativeLayout getPageAt(int index){
    RelativeLayout rl =  ((RelativeLayout)((ViewGroup)pager.findViewById(R.id.home_container)).getChildAt(index));
    return rl;
}
```

Comment: `getChildAt(pager.getCurrentItem())` doesn't do what you want. For example ViewPager can have 1000 pages, but only 5 childen, so you're going out of bounds if current item is the last page.

Comment: @fdermishin this is true unless you have the option 'setOffscreenPageLimit(N-1)' where N is the number of pages. This is not advised though if you have many pages because it can be an unnecessary waste of memory

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 final int position = mViewPager.getCurrentItem();
    Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("android:switcher:" + R.id.rewards_viewpager + ":"
            + position);
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to do it more general, so I decided to use the private 'position' of ViewPager.LayoutParams

```
        final int childCount = viewPager.getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
            final View child = viewPager.getChildAt(i);
            final ViewPager.LayoutParams lp = (ViewPager.LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();
            int position = 0;
            try {
                Field f = lp.getClass().getDeclaredField("position");
                f.setAccessible(true);
                position = f.getInt(lp); //IllegalAccessException
            } catch (NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException ex) {ex.printStackTrace();}
            if (position == viewPager.getCurrentItem()) {
                viewToDraw = child;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using [ViewPagerUtils](https://github.com/Krupen/FabulousFilter/blob/master/fabulousfilter/src/main/java/android/support/v4/view/ViewPagerUtils.java) from [FabulousFilter](https://github.com/Krupen/FabulousFilter):

```
ViewPagerUtils.getCurrentView(ViewPager viewPager)
```

Comment: I'm using this method and I can confirm that it works.

Comment: This is not part of the core android SDK. You are probably using a third party library. That is likely why you were downvoted.

Comment: Are you using this library? https://github.com/Krupen/FabulousFilter. This library has a ViewPagerUtils method. It uses the android.support.v4 namespace which is HIGHLY suspect. You should NEVER EVER use android namespaces for your classes, as it can lead to confusion (this being a perfect example of such confusion). It seems the author did this to access package protected fields, which once again is a terrible code practice. I would not recommend this method.

Comment: I wrote in the answer that it's the android support library v4. https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/

Comment: And the ViewPager is part of the Support Library so no additional dependency needs to be added.

Comment: ViewPager is part of the support library of course, but ViewPagerUtils does not exist in the support library.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to do this is by overrideing the `onViewAttachedToWindow(holder: Holder)` method in adapter class (extension of RecyclerView.Adapter).

Also if you want to perform some operations (freeing up resources, stopping animation listeners etc) on the view which just swiped away, it can be done by overriding the `onViewDetachedFromWindow(holder: Holder)` in the adapter class.

Comment: This absolutely saved me for the final project of my Android class due in 20 hours. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

is that your first activity on the screen or have you layered some above each other already?

try this:

```
findViewById(android.R.id.content).getRootView()
```

or just:

```
findViewById(android.R.id.content)
```

also depending on what you want try:

```
((ViewGroup)findViewById(android.R.id.content)).getChildAt(0)
```

Comment: first twoo just give me the TAB 0 item, all the time, and the third code give me a null

Comment: tried this? this.findViewById(android.R.id.content).getRootView()   Maybe you should give some more info about your activities and how you construct and move between them.

Comment: None of those suggestions will work. The 3rd one will get a page in the pager but not the centre view but one to the left and the OP wanted the centred/current page.

Answer (score 0):

You can find fragment by system tag. It's work for me. I used it in `OnMeasure` function.

`id` - viewPager ID

`position` - fragment which you want to get

Important! You get this fragment if your fragment was created in adapter. So you must to check `supportedFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("android:switcher:" + id + ":" + position)` nullify

You can get view like this:

```
supportedFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("android:switcher:" + id + ":" + position).view
```

You shouldn't give custom tag in adapter

Answer (score 0):

**You can get it by viewpager listener to get slected item position**

```
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(object : ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener{
        override fun onPageScrolled(position: Int, positionOffset: Float, positionOffsetPixels: Int) {
            
        }

        override fun onPageSelected(position: Int) {
            
        }

        override fun onPageScrollStateChanged(state: Int) {
            
        }

    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this method.

```
View getCurrentView(ViewPager viewPager) {
        try {
            final int currentItem = viewPager.getCurrentItem();
            for (int i = 0; i < viewPager.getChildCount(); i++) {
                final View child = viewPager.getChildAt(i);
                final ViewPager.LayoutParams layoutParams = (ViewPager.LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();

                Field f = layoutParams.getClass().getDeclaredField("position"); //NoSuchFieldException
                f.setAccessible(true);
                int position = (Integer) f.get(layoutParams); //IllegalAccessException

                if (!layoutParams.isDecor && currentItem == position) {
                    return child;
                }
            }
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
        }
        return null;
    }
```

it will may return null in androidx if anybody knows the solution comment here

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you can't call `getChildAt(getCurrentItem())` directly on the `ViewPager`. You should call it on the underlying `RecyclerViewImpl` which exists at `getChildAt(0)`.

```
View view = viewPager.getChildAt(0).getChildAt(viewPager.getCurrentItem);
```

Answer (score -3):

Please check this

```
((ViewGroup))mViewPager.getChildAt(MyActivity.mViewPager.getCurrentItem()));
```

else verify [this link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html).

Comment: not working, this get not that View that is visible sadly, and sometimes get null

Comment: This doesn't work. The range of `getChildAt()` is different than the range of `getCurrentItem()`. For example if your ViewPager shows 20 items and 1 offscreen page, then `getChildAt()`'s range is 0-2 while `getCurrentItem()`'s range is 0-19. You'd mostly get null return values.

Answer (score -3):

If you examine carefully, there are at most 3 views saved by ViewPager.
You can easily get the current view by

```
view     = MyActivity.mViewPager.getChildAt(1);
```

Comment: This doesn't work. What if the viewpager is showing its first or last page? What if there's more than 1 offscreen page?

Comment: False, you can set ViewPager to cache more than 3 views with `setOffscreenPageLimit(int)`