# Android: ViewPager FragmentStatePagerAdapter get current View

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragmentstatepageradapter

**Question**: How to get current View of a ViewPager FragmentStatePagerAdapter?

1. I have spent almost 24 hours on this and searched everywhere for the fit solutions.
2. Get current position is easy, I already got that. This is get current **View**.
3. `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` is required, not `PagerAdapter`.

   - [This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12854783/android-viewpager-get-the-current-view) suggested **setTag** and **findViewWithTag** via `instantiateItem(View container, int position)`. This is for PagerAdapter.
   - However in `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` the *instantiateItem* has a *ViewGroup* param **not** *View* param: `instantiateItem(**ViewGroup** container, int position)`

So I hope it's not impossible, is it? Please help!

Answer (score 4):

You can use the *setTag* trick with the view you are returning in your **instantiateItem** method.

Here, I'm using a ViewPager with PagerAdapter, but I think this idea might work for you too.

So, when you are instantiating your views (in PagerAdapter the method is also **instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position)**), you should use ***setTag*** to your view.

Like this: 

`view.setTag("view" + position);` 
`return view;`

So, when you need the *current view*, you should do this: `View view = (View) pager.findViewWithTag("view" + pager.getCurrentItem());`, where **pager** is the ViewPager, which you can get passing it by params from your Activity to your adapter.

Comment: sorry for the late reply and thanks for the help. How did you get the 'view' in your 'view.setTag()' while the param is 'ViewGroup container'?

Comment: Sorry for the even later reply. 
Actually the view that I was talking about is the view you return in the end of **instantiateItem**.