# Add imageview inside one slide in a viewpager, how to attach the image to right viewgroup

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have a navigation drawer and `ViewPager` where one can chose an object from a list in the drawer. When clicked/ touched I want to add that image to the active slide in the `ViewPager`.

I have made a method `addObjectToSlide()` which does that, but the image is attached to wrong View. When I slide from one page to another, the image is stuck on top. Also when I open the drawer, the image is over that.

Here is my code:

```
private void addObjectToSlide(int pageNumber, int position) {
    ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.scroll_view_slides).getRootView();
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams imParams =
            new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    imParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    ImageView iv = new ImageView(rootView.getContext());

    switch (pageNumber) {
        case 0 :
            iv.setImageDrawable(getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.p1_object).getDrawable(position));
            break;
        default:
            // add later
    }
    rootView.addView(iv, imParams);
}
```

`scroll_view_slides` is the `RelativeLayout` id for `fragment_screen_slide_page.xml`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, I changed the following sentences:

```
ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) mViewPager.findViewWithTag(pageNumber);
```

After reading this [question and solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12854783/android-viewpager-get-the-current-view).