# Android Custom ListView CursorAdapter updating the last item

Tags: android, listview

I'm having issue with my custom listview (CursorAdapter)

When I click btAdd on 2nd item, it's updating the last list item. And also, when I click an item, it doesn't display this

```
Log.e("Selected", "" + position);
```

What I wanna do is to update the edittext of the 2nd item or whatever is the selected item.

MainActivity.class

```
private void initControls(View rootView) {

    lv = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    MyTextView tvHeader = (MyTextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tvHeader);

    DatabaseHelper dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getActivity());
    DBConnector.dbConnect(dbHelper);

    cursor = dbHelper.getAllItems(user);

    adapterProd = new CustomAdapter(getActivity(), cursor);
    lv.setAdapter(adapterProd);
    adapterProd.notifyDataSetChanged();

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                int position, long id) {
            Log.e("Selected", "" + position);
        }
    });

    if(adapterProd.getCount() < 1) {
        tvHeader.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        tvHeader.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.no_saved_items));
    } else {
        tvHeader.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

}

class CustomAdapter extends CursorAdapter
{
    TextView name, price, description;
    EditText etQuantity;
    ImageButton ibAdd, ibSubtract;
    ImageView img;
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public CustomAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
        super(context, c);
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(final View itemView, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

        name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById (R.id.tvName);
        price = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvPrice);
        description = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvDescription);
        etQuantity = (EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.etQuantity);
        etQuantity.append(String.valueOf(quantity));
        etQuantity.setSelection(etQuantity.getText().length());
        ibAdd = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ibAdd);
        ibSubtract = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ibSubtract);
        img = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        checkBox = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);

        final String selected =
                cursor.getString(
                        cursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.KEY_ID));

        checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {
                    //Case 1
                    Log.e("Selected", "" + selected);
                    itemView.setPressed(true);
                }
                else {
                    //case 2
                    Log.e("Deselected", "" + selected);
                    itemView.setPressed(false);
                }

            }
        });

        ibAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                quantity++;
                etQuantity.setText(String.valueOf(quantity));
            }
        });

        ibSubtract.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                quantity--;
                if(quantity < 1) {
                    quantity = 1;
                }
                etQuantity.setText(String.valueOf(quantity));
            }
        });


        if(cursor.getString(
            cursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.KEY_PRODUCT_NAME)) != null) {
            name.setText(cursor.getString(
                cursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.KEY_PRODUCT_NAME)));
            price.setText(Formatter.formatWithPesoSign(cursor.getString(
                    cursor.getColumnIndex(
                            Constants.KEY_PRODUCT_PRICE))));
            description.setText(cursor.getString(
                cursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.KEY_PRODUCT_NAME)));
        } else {
            price.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            name.setText(cursor.getString(
                cursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.KEY_PRODUCT_PARTITION_KEY)));
            description.setText(cursor.getString(
                cursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.KEY_PRODUCT_ROW_KEY)));

            if(ConnectionDetector.hasNetworkConnection(getActivity())) {
                GetSavedItemAsyncTask task = new GetSavedItemAsyncTask(
                    getActivity(), accessToken, sessionKey,
                    cursor.getString(
                        cursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.KEY_PRODUCT_PARTITION_KEY)),
                    cursor.getString(
                        cursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.KEY_PRODUCT_ROW_KEY)),
                    cursor.getString(
                        cursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.KEY_ID)),
                    user);
                task.execute();
            }

        }

        Picasso.with(getActivity())
                .load(Constants.displayProductThumbnail(Constants.MERCHANT,
                        cursor.getString(
                                cursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.KEY_PRODUCT_ROW_KEY)), "200"))
                .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
                .into(img);


    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);

    }

}
```

list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="10dp"
android:paddingRight="10dp"
android:paddingBottom="5dp"
android:clickable="true"
android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/card_background_selector"
    android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants">


        <ImageView
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView" />

        <TextView
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:id="@+id/tvName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/name"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/checkBox"/>

        <TextView
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:id="@+id/tvPrice"
            android:textColor="@color/cadmium_orange"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/price"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tvDescription"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvDescription"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/description"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tvName"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/quantity"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tvPrice"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView" >

            <ImageButton
                style="@style/My.Button"
                android:id="@+id/ibSubtract"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_remove_white_36dp"
                android:padding="5dp" />

            <EditText
                android:background="#fff"
                android:id="@+id/etQuantity"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:inputType="number" />

            <ImageButton
                style="@style/My.Button"
                android:id="@+id/ibAdd"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_add_white_36dp"
                android:padding="5dp" />


        </LinearLayout>

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/checkBox"
        android:checked="false" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Any ideas? I would gladly appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ibAdd` Button click always update last row `etQuantity` TextView  because `etQuantity` is reference to TextView which is return by `getView` method on last call.

To update clicked row TextView value use `setTag/getTag` method to get clicked row in `onClick` of `ibAdd` and `ibSubtract` Buttons. like:

```
ibAdd.setTag(etQuantity);
ibAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                TextView etQuantityView=(TextView)v.getTag();
                quantity++;
                etQuantityView.setText(String.valueOf(quantity));
            }
        });
```

Do same on `ibSubtract`  Button click to show subtracted value

Comment: I'm getting NPE on that line TextView etQuantityView=(TextView)v.getTag();, and why is lv.setOnItemClickListener not firing?

Comment: @bEtTyBarnes: you are asking wrong row is updating on click but then you are trying to add new question `why is lv.setOnItemClickListener not firing?`

Comment: @bEtTyBarnes: you are using also `ibAdd.setTag(etQuantity);` line?

Comment: Please check my post "When I click btAdd on 2nd item, it's updating the last list item. And also, when I click an item, it doesn't display this

Log.e("Selected", "" + position);"

Comment: Remove `android:clickable="true" android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"` attributes from xml then check it's working or not

Comment: @bEtTyBarnes: search for [ListView setOnItemClickListener not working in custom list view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6703390/listview-setonitemclicklistener-not-working-by-adding-button) you will get lots of post related to same issue

Comment: It's updating the correct row but when I update quantity of a row and I update another, it's getting the last quantity and then adding it.

Comment: @bEtTyBarnes: then also save `etQuantity` value in `etQuantity` using `setTag` like `etQuantity.setTag(etQuantity)` and get same on Button click before increment and decrement and save again updated value in same object from which you have retrieved

Comment: Is this correct? I put etQuantity.setTag(etQuantity) below ibAdd.setTag(etQuantity); Btw, quantity is integer

Comment: @bEtTyBarnes: use `Put etQuantity.setTag(quantity)` and on button click `int prevQuantity=Integer.parseInt(etQuantityView.getTag().toString());prevQuantity++;etQuantityView.setText(String.valueOf(prevQuantity));etQuantityView.setTag(prevQuantity.toString())`

Answer (score 0):

This is improving on ρяσѕρєя K's answer (which had worked for me). This is a better way of using two tags:

```
ibAdd.setTag(R.id.TAG_ID_1, etQuantity);
ibAdd.setTag(R.id.TAG_ID_2, new Integer(quantity));
ibAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        TextView etQuantityView = (TextView) v.getTag(R.id.TAG_ID_1);
        int prevQuantity = (Integer) v.getTag(R.id.TAG_ID_2);
        prevQuantity++;
        etQuantityView.setText(String.valueOf(prevQuantity));
    }
});
```

NOTE: The ids *R.id.TAG_ID_1* and *R.id.TAG_ID_2* are required to be defined in the *res/values* folder as *tags.xml*. The contents are like this:

```
<resources>
    <item name="TAG_ID_1" type="id"/>
    <item name="TAG_ID_2" type="id"/>
</resources>
```