# Error "You must not call setTag() on a view Glide is targeting" when use Glide

Tags: android, android-glide

I use [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) library inner custom adapter view in my apps. But I have Error :

```
"You must not call setTag() on a view Glide is targeting"
```

This part of my code :

```
 @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup container) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (view == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            view = holder.imageView = new ImageView(context);
            view.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }

        holder.imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams vp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        holder.imageView .setLayoutParams(vp);
        holder.imageView .setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);

        String var_news_article_images = imageIdList.get(getPosition(position));

        Glide.with(context)
                .load(var_news_article_images)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
               .into(holder.imageView);

               return view;
    }
```

so how to fix it ?

Comment: Wrap your ImageView inside a ViewGroup (LinearLayout for instance).

Comment: @AmayDiam I have posted the solution! have a nice day!

Answer (score 75):

The key is `ViewTarget.setTagId`; setting it will free up the default `setTag` on the `ImageView` so you can use it as root in the item layout.
It was introduced in Glide 3.6.0 in [issue #370](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/370).

In your manifest add this:

```
<application
        android:name=".App"
```

Then create an application context class:

```
public class App extends Application {
    @Override public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        ViewTarget.setTagId(R.id.glide_tag);
    }
}
```

Add the following as contents for `src/main/values/ids.xml`:

```
<resources>
    <item type="id" name="glide_tag" />
</resources>
```

(or just add the above `<item ... />` into any `resources` xml in `values`)

**Update**: `ViewTarget` was deprecated since 4.8.0. If you're using `into(ImageView)`, you'll still have to call the deprecated class's method, because the built-in `*ViewTarget` classes still extend the old class.

If you use a custom `ViewTarget`, migrate to `CustomViewTarget` as the replacement. This will remove the need for setting any tag ID, because the default behaviour for `CustomViewTarget` is using a Glide-specific ID, so it shouldn't clash with any `setTag` calls.
If you want to customise the ID anyway, you can use `useTagId` on your custom target.

Comment: This solutions DOESN´t WORK. The solution is just  avoid the call of setTag() method.

Comment: @Elenasys This approach configures Glide to be compatible with single-`ImageView` list items. I opened [#370](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/370) which resulted in adding the `setTagId` method almost a year before this question anticipating that it may come up later. Glide has to associate Requests with Targets (Views) somehow and this is how it was designed originally and it works well in the most cases. Other times you may need a little configuration, just like with any other framework/library.

Comment: @Elenasys It actually works. Just tried it. Calling setTag() is sometimes inevitable especially if the ImageView is a custom view from a third party library.

Comment: @JasonStack it's really simple, just follow where that ID goes and who calls `getRequest()`. Glide stores the request object in the view's default tag by default. Notice the different overload of `setTag` based on presence of custom ID.

Comment: ViewTarget is deprecated!

Answer (score 20):

`Glide` use `setTag(Object)` method internally. So remove all calls of `setTag(Object)` from your target view. ie `ImageView`

If you really required to use `setTag` method on your view, you can use `setTag(int,Object)` method instead.

Comment: Thanks. If using any integer constant as the first parameter, you will receive an exception: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The key must be an application-specific resource id.`. So, see the accepted answer or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2859574/the-key-must-be-an-application-specific-resource-id.

Comment: Yes, You need to use Resource for First parameter. As mentioned in SetTag(int,Object) JavaDoc

Answer (score 3):

From what I've found from Googling, seems like Glide and ViewHolder don't get along too well. I tried Picasso instead. Problem solved instantly.

You can also try the solution from TWiStErRob, but make sure you're using Glide 3.6.0 or higher. It did not recognize setTagId(int) on 3.5.2

Comment: Thanks for the version tip, I updated my answer. We're at 3.7.0 and there's no reason not to use the latest (Glide is semver'd).

Comment: Another soft fix for this that I used is, wrap the ImageView in some other view like CardView and now set the tag for the card view. (If you have to use the tag).

Answer (score 2):

```
ImageView mImageAds = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_img);
 mImageAds.setTag(R.id.iv_img, i); // "i" means some integer value
 Glide.with(getActivity()).load(urlPath)
                          .placeholder(R.drawable.ads_banner)
                          .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                          .into(mImageAds);

mImageAds.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            if(mImageAds.getTag() != null) {
                                int position = (Integer) view.getTag(R.id.iv_img);
                                //code here what would you like to do.
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

See also : https://androidhiker.blogspot.com/2015/10/how-to-resolve-glide-settag-issue.html

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, after removing the following

```
android:tag="xx"
```

from the image on my xml layout, that issue was gone

Answer (score 1):

If you have freedom to *use other library*, use, else 
you can use *setTag(int, Object)*, but **if you can't do above then** wrap ImageView in a basic LinearLayout > setTag() on LinearLayout > setOnClickListener on LinearLayout.

Something like :

```
LinearLayout imgViewLinearLayout = new LinearLayout(context);
            imgViewLinearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
            imgViewLinearLayout.setId(R.id.dummy_image_layout);
            imgViewLinearLayout.setOnClickListener(this);

ImageView imageView = new ImageView(inflater.getContext());
                imageView.setPadding(0,15,20,0);

                imageView.setId(R.id.imageview_for_glide);

                imgViewLinearLayout.setTag("Image VIEWTAG");
imgViewLinearLayout.addView(imageView)
```

Override onClick and :

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if(v.getId() == R.id.dummy_image_layout){
            //Do what you wanna wanted to do on click of ImageView
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

As written by `Thu Thu`, you can simply reference an `id` of any existing `View`. For instance, suppose you want to set tag to an `ImageView`:

```
image_view.setTag(R.id.image_view, 100)
if (image_view.getTag(R.id.image_view) == 100) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Use view.setTage(int, object); and view.getTag(int);