# How can I take singleRequest model by Glide?

Tags: android, image, imageview, android-glide

I can load image path to imageView using Glide in this code:

```
GlideApp.with(context)
                .load(imagePath)
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .transition(withCrossFade())
                .into(imageView);
```

**I do not want to load previously registered same path or bitmap from imageView**.

==============UPDATE=================

I find this solution (thanks ADM):

Glide automatically performs `setTag()` function and when I call `imageView.getTag()` function, result is deriving `SingleRequest` which has loaded data (imagePath or bitmap).

But I can't access singleRequest `model` field, it is a private. How can I take singleRequest `model` field? Please help me.

Comment: ImageView does not contain image path. You basically can't get it from the ImageView. You are trying to use some weird solution of the problem. Better just tell us what is the problem, why you want to get that image path

Comment: I do not want load previously registered same path or bitmap from imageView..What should I do for this?

Comment: Then you have to store somewhere (in a `Map`?) which path you have loaded in which ImageView, and check it before loading

Comment: Glide cache mechanism doing this?

Comment: probably. I'm not using Glide, I use Picasso instead. Picasso is doing caching.

Comment: what you need exactly from image in imageview ???@propoLis

Comment: I want to loaded image path or bitmap for don't the same picture upload.

Comment: exactly my question is how to do that

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko I will use your method, mapping

Comment: Sure. The reason I don't want to write a full answer is because it depends on more of your code, and is quite easy to implement if you just know the idea.

Comment: If you only need path which loaded into imageview then why don't just tag it to Imageview .

Comment: sorry, I don't understand @ADM

Comment: There is a setTag() method for each view .you can set the url as tag and get it later . Only if I understood the problem correct..

Comment: @ADM very thanks. Please see my updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed you should tag e url with `view.setTag()`.

Here `setTag(Object object)` takes object as argument . Whenever we call `getTag()` we need to cast it. below is the example.

```
 view.setTag("htttp://www.imgur.3877383.jpg");
    String url =(String)view.getTag();
    if(url!=null){
        // Use the url
    }
```

Cause Argument  is an Object so you can also add class object as tag.

```
   view.setTag(myPozo);
    MyPozo myPozo =(MyPozo)view.getTag();
    if(myPozo!=null){
        // Use the pozo
    }
```

Also i am not aware with the use of this . But if you are working on List (ListView or RecyclerView etc) then you can directly access the dataset attached with the view by position.

Comment: Glide automatically performs `setTag()` function and when I call `getTag()` function is deriving `SingleRequest`. Glide SingleRequest has a model which has loaded path or image bitmap but singleRequest model is private and I haven't access this model

Comment: Yeah i doubted that . Sorry not much familiar with GLide .Anyway i will look into issue .

Comment: well there is also key implementation of `settag()`. See if it works out for you . https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag(int, java.lang.Object) . You can set your own tag .

Comment: Yeah I know but Glide does not allow me to use setTag function. Throw this exception: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You must not call setTag() on a view Glide is targeting`

Comment: Yeah that happens with image loaders . Here is the thing you need to edit your question with proper detail . Why you need this ? May be there is simple workaround .

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35096552/4168607) might solve your problem . Take a good look at it . Glide migrate to `setTag(int id, Object value)` . Good luck

Comment: thank you very very much!! Sorrry, You have very tired

Answer (score 0):

you can't take "image path" from imageView by using Glide or any other libraries, one can set image bitmap or background in the imageView so you can get bitmap back from imageview if you want but you cannot get imagepath back from imageview.
if you wants to remember image path with you are going to apply as a bitmap in imageview you can do it via add the image path to arraylist and use it when needed

Try this code :

```
Glide.with(this).load(Uri.parse(resultUri)).asBitmap().into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {

                @Override
                public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, GlideAnimation<? super Bitmap> glideAnimation) {

                    if (resource != null) {

                        myTouchView1.setImageBitmap(resource);
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: I do not want load previously registered same path or bitmap from imageView..What should I do for this?

Answer (score -2):

You should read:

[Guide Documentation](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)

The imagepath will be something like:

```
String asseturl = "file:///android_asset/demo1.jpg";
Glide.with(context).load(asserturl)....
```

Comment: I do not want load previously registered same path or bitmap from imageView.What should I do for this?