# Tag alternative when using Glide

Tags: android, android-glide

I am trying to make a puzzle game. I wanted to use `setTag()/getTag()` to identify which image is in which tile (`ImageView`) and to swap them when the users clicks one tile and then another one.
Apparently you can't use `setTag()/getTag()` when using Glide - `You must not call setTag() on a view Glide is targeting`

Is there a `setTag()/getTag()` alternative or a best-practive solution for this ? - 
Glide newbie btw.

Thank you for your time.

-- This is the adapter. `image.setTag()` here is illegal --

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context mContext;

    // references to drawables
    private int[] mThumbIds = {
            R.drawable.puzzle_0_0,
            R.drawable.puzzle_0_1,
            R.drawable.puzzle_0_2,
            R.drawable.puzzle_0_3,
            R.drawable.puzzle_1_0,
            R.drawable.puzzle_1_1,
            R.drawable.puzzle_1_2,
            R.drawable.puzzle_1_3,
            R.drawable.puzzle_2_0,
            R.drawable.puzzle_2_1,
            R.drawable.puzzle_2_2,
            R.drawable.puzzle_2_3,
            R.drawable.puzzle_3_0,
            R.drawable.puzzle_3_1,
            R.drawable.puzzle_3_2,
            R.drawable.puzzle_3_3,
    };

    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
        shuffleArray(mThumbIds);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mThumbIds[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView image;
        if (convertView == null) {
            image = new ImageView(mContext);
            image.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
        }
        else {
            image = (ImageView) convertView;
        }
        Glide.with(mContext).load(mThumbIds[position]).into(image);
        image.setTag(mThumbIds[position]);

        return image;
    }

    private static void shuffleArray(int[] a) {
        Random rng = new Random();
        for (int i = a.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
            int index = rng.nextInt(i + 1);
            // Simple swap
            int temp = a[index];
            a[index] = a[i];
            a[i] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

-- Here is the `getView()` --

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // references to drawables
    private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
            R.drawable.puzzle_0_0,
            R.drawable.puzzle_0_1,
            R.drawable.puzzle_0_2,
            R.drawable.puzzle_0_3,
            R.drawable.puzzle_1_0,
            R.drawable.puzzle_1_1,
            R.drawable.puzzle_1_2,
            R.drawable.puzzle_1_3,
            R.drawable.puzzle_2_0,
            R.drawable.puzzle_2_1,
            R.drawable.puzzle_2_2,
            R.drawable.puzzle_2_3,
            R.drawable.puzzle_3_0,
            R.drawable.puzzle_3_1,
            R.drawable.puzzle_3_2,
            R.drawable.puzzle_3_3,
    };
    public GridView gridView;
    private boolean swapping = false;
    private int firstTilePosition;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        gridView = findViewById(R.id.gridView);
        gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Log.d("-MyLog-", view.getTag().toString());

                if (!swapping) {
                    firstTilePosition = position;
                    swapping = true;
                }
                else {
                    ImageView firstTile = (ImageView) parent.getChildAt(firstTilePosition);
                    ImageView secondTile = (ImageView) view;

                    int firstTag = (int) firstTile.getTag();
                    int secondTag = (int) secondTile.getTag();

                    Glide.with(MainActivity.this).load(secondTag).into(firstTile);
                    Glide.with(MainActivity.this).load(firstTag).into(secondTile);

                    firstTile.setTag(secondTag);
                    secondTile.setTag(firstTag);

                    // Replace with AlertDialog
                    if ( gameWon(parent) )
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Game Won !!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    swapping = false;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private boolean gameWon(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        for (int i = 0; i < parent.getChildCount(); i++) {
            if ( ((int) parent.getChildAt(i).getTag()) != mThumbIds[i] )
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error "You must not call setTag() on a view Glide is targeting" when use Glide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34833627/error-you-must-not-call-settag-on-a-view-glide-is-targeting-when-use-glide)

Answer (score 0):

You can reserve the default tag for Glide and use the key-based tag for yourself.

```
myButton.setTag(100 /* or any other integer key except 0 */, someValue);
```