# Unable to setTag and getTag for Viewholder in ExpandableListView

Tags: java, android, expandablelistview, android-viewholder

I'm working on an expandable list that has different layouts in different child items. I'm also using `viewHolder` method to cached the views. The app crashes with this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The key must be an application-specific resource id.
```

I know it needs something like a layout id as the key, but the only way to bring up the right `viewHolder` is the `childType` in this case:

```
int childType = getChildType(groupPosition, childPosition);

if (convertView == null || convertView.getTag(childType) != null) {
   viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
   convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
   viewHolder.text = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
   convertView.setTag(childType,viewHolder);

}else{

   viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag(childType);
}

if(childType == 0){
    /***Render Stuff***/
}
```

How can I use `childType` to call up the viewHolder for different types of child items?

Complete Code:

```
public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter{

    private Context context;

    private Map<String, List<?>> dataCollections;

    public ExpandableListAdapter(FragmentActivity context, List<String> laptops,
            Map<String, List<?>> dataCollections) {
        this.context = context;

        this.dataCollections = dataCollections;

    }


    public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
            boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        MappingItem row = (MappingItem) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);  

        int childType = getChildType(groupPosition, childPosition);

        ViewHolder viewHolder;

        if (convertView == null || convertView.getTag(childType) != null) {

            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            if(childType == 0){

               convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);

               viewHolder.text = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);

            }

            convertView.setTag(childType,viewHolder);
                                 ^^^^^^
        }else {

            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag(childType);

        }

        if(childType == 0){

               /********Render Something**********/

        }

        return convertView;
    }


}
```

Comment: Thing is that you are not using a unique key to store the tag, thats why you are seeing the crash, you are supposed to use unique keys for each new tag, and what I can guess in your case is that childType is not unique for each item

Comment: @Bhargav, thanks, I have also tried to use childId, `int childId = (int) getChildId(groupPosition, childPosition);` still not working

Comment: why do you need to set a key? are you storing multiple tags in a single view?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The key must be an application-specific resource id](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2859574/the-key-must-be-an-application-specific-resource-id)

Comment: just refer to this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/2859685/4848308