# Android: How to specify a TAG or identifier to a file

Tags: android

I have to attach a long unique string to each file in my directory. Now If I set the identifier string to the name of the file it will look messy. So is there maybe a way in android to attach a some how TAG to a file and still be able to retrieve this TAG?

Thanks.

Comment: refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2859574/the-key-must-be-an-application-specific-resource-id?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: @MohammadAli what does this have to do with the question?

Comment: what db do you use?