# Navigation DESTINATION_NAME is unknown to this NavController, ReOpening fragment previously closed using navController.popBackStack()?

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-jetpack, android-architecture-navigation

I am using Navigation Component in my app , recently it was working correctly but after updating project to `AndroidX` I am getting error `navigation destination DESTINATION_NAME is unknown to this NavController` **only if  that destination(Which I'm going to open) is previously closed from itself using `navController.popBackStack()`**. Also, There is no error if I close DESTINATION fragment from `MainActivity`, But Error only Occurs fragment is closed from itself using `popBackStack`. like below

*DestinationFragment*

```
viewModelOfActivity.handleBackButton.observe(this, Observer {
        Navigation.findNavController(requireActivity(), R.id.main_nav_host).popBackStack() 
        //CALLING popBackStack() HERE CAUSING PROBLEM WHEN REOPNING THIS DESTINATION(or frg ) AGIAN
})
```

*MainActivity*

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
    if (myViewModel.isDefaultBehaviour.value == true) {
        super.onBackPressed()
    } else{
        myViewModel.handleBackButton.value=true
        //NO ERROR IF HANDLE BACK BUTTON HERE ie->findNavController(R.id.main_nav_host).popBackStack()
       //INSTEAD OF myViewModel.handleBackButton
    }
}
```

I Have also checked related Question but no help [Similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51060762/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-navigation-destination-xxx-is-unknown-to-thi).

NOTE: I am using the latest version of the navigation library (alpha05)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using [SingleLiveEvent](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/blob/dev-todo-mvvm-live/todoapp/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/architecture/blueprints/todoapp/SingleLiveEvent.java) in  *DestinationFragment* to observe back press from *MainActivity* as I have already mentioned this in my question. So the problem was in `SingleLiveEvent` I noticed that I have accidently changed code of `fun observe(owner: LifecycleOwner, observer: Observer<in T>)` to

```
override fun observe(owner: LifecycleOwner, observer: Observer<in T>) {
    super.observe(owner, observer)//Here is problem I was calling super twice in function
    if (hasActiveObservers()) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Multiple observers registered but only one will be notified of changes.")
    }
    super.observe(owner, Observer { t ->/** other code*//})
}
```

Here you can see I was calling `super` function twice which calls `onChanged` of observer twice in `Fragment` , below code is called twice
`Navigation.findNavController(requireActivity(), R.id.main_nav_host).popBackStack()`
which `popBackStack()` twice.
Then I have changed `observe` function like below

```
@MainThread
override fun observe(owner: LifecycleOwner, observer: Observer<in T>) {
    if (hasActiveObservers()) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Multiple observers registered but only one will be notified of changes.")
    }
    super.observe(owner, Observer { t ->/** other code*//})
}
```

Now my code works fine

Answer (score 0):

The previous value likely still exists in the view model and is triggering right away. I'd recommend using an interface to handle your back button delegation instead of an observer. That should fix the usage.

What's happening is you're popping too far up your back stack to the point where you don't have an active graph anymore. This is happening because your observer is getting triggered more often than it should. To see this, I'd recommend debugging that line and inspecting the graph right before a crash. It's likely to be null.

Comment: i'm using [SingleLiveEvent](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/blob/dev-todo-mvvm-live/todoapp/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/architecture/blueprints/todoapp/SingleLiveEvent.java) which only triggers once

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. In my app there were three fragments `A -> B -> C` and I had to return to `A` from `C`. In my case I used `popBackStack()` to close the current fragment and return to the previous one, after that any attempt to navigate from `A` threw `Navigation xxx is unknown to this NavController` exception.

I ended up using `navigate()` to `A` instead of pop fragments from back stack. Using `popUpTo` and `popUpToInclusive` settings properly fixed the issue (see docs https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started#popupto_example_circular_logic)

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/FragmentC"
    android:name="xxx.FragmentC"
    android:label="C" >
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_to_A"
        app:destination="@id/FragmentA"
        app:popUpTo="@+id/FragmentA"
        app:popUpToInclusive="true" />
</fragment>
```

Answer (score 0):

i am use this way

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

 if(myNavController.getCurrentDestination().getId()==R.id.startDestinationId)
 /** do something */
 else myNavController.popBackStack();

}
```