# Jetpack navigation initiating previous screen

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-navigation

I have this simple navigation setup consisting of 3 screens:

```
Screen 1 -> Screen 2 -> Screen 3
    |______________________^
```

Screen 2 is the signup form that can be skipped when completed once.

I have this weird issue with a Jetpack navigation graph where when navigating from Screen 2 -> 3 the app crashed because of Screen 1 (!) `onViewCreated()` activated and navigation directions cannot be found:

```
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: navigation destination 
com.example.app:id/action_screen1_to_screen3 is unknown to this NavController
```

My navigation graph:

```
   <fragment
        android:id="@+id/screen1"
        android:name="Screen1Fragment"
        android:label="Screen 1"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_screen_1">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_screen1_to_screen2"
            app:destination="@id/screen2"
            app:launchSingleTop="false"/>
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_screen1_to_screen3"
            app:destination="@id/screen3"
            app:launchSingleTop="false"
            app:popUpTo="@id/screen1"
            app:popUpToInclusive="true" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/screen2"
        android:name="Screen2Fragment"
        android:label="Screen 2"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_screen_2">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_screen2_to_screen3"
            app:destination="@id/screen3"
            app:launchSingleTop="false"
            app:popUpTo="@id/screen2"
            app:popUpToInclusive="true" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/screen3"
        android:name="Screen3Fragment"
        android:label="Screen 3"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_screen_3">
    </fragment>
```

I am using auto-generated NavDirections so it's not a matter of using the wrong resource id.

Navigation code:

```
// Screen 1
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        if (isLoggedIn) {
            view?.findNavController()
                ?.navigate(Screen1FragmentDirections.screen1ToSelectScreen3())
        } else {
            signInButton.setOnClickListener {
                val action =
                    Screen1FragmentDirections.screen1ToScreen2()
                view?.findNavController()?.navigate(action)
            }
        }
    }

// Screen 2
view?.findNavController()?.navigate(Screen2FragmentDirections.screen2ToScreen3())
```

My Gradle imports:

```
    def nav_version = "2.3.0-alpha04"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$nav_version"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$nav_version"
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Can you try adding this top level variable : `val navController = Navigation.findNavController(activity, R.id.nav_host_fragment)` and changing `view?.findNavController().navigate` by  and calling `navController.navigate`

Comment: Just tried using a single navController like you suggested, same result (I have a single navHost anyway).

Comment: Any ideas why Screen 1 is called in the first place? Is it the popUpTo?

Comment: It seems this issue is known here are a few articles that might help you, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51060762/illegalargumentexception-navigation-destination-xxx-is-unknown-to-this-navcontr, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51887968/navigation-destination-name-is-unknown-to-this-navcontroller-reopening-fragment, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54689361/avoiding-android-navigation-illegalargumentexception-in-navcontroller

Comment: Thanks @Biscuit for your help! This wasn't the issue but lead to a workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why it's happening but the solution I found was instead of popUpTo until the current screen, is to popUpTo the entire navigation graph:

```
[...]
app:popUpTo="@id/nav_graph"
app:popUpToInclusive="true"
[...]
```