# Avoiding Android navigation IllegalArgumentException in NavController

Tags: android, android-architecture-navigation

I recently switched over to Android Navigation, but have encountered a fair amount of situations (in different parts of the code), where I get:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
navigation destination com.xxx.yyy:id/action_aFragment_to_bFragment is unknown to this NavController
```

In every case, the code are simple calls like:

```
findNavController(this, R.id.navigation_host_fragment).navigate(R.id.action_aFragment_to_bFragment)
```

Usually in response to a button press.

It's unclear why this error is getting thrown. My current suspicion is that the onClickListener is somehow getting called twice on some devices, causing the navigate to be called a second time (causing it to be in the wrong state at the time). The reason for this suspicion is that this most often seems to happen in cases where one might have a "long" running operation before the navigate call. I can't recreate this on my own device, though.

Ideas on how to avoid this issue (or indeed, what the actual root cause of the issue is)?

I don't want to use Global Actions; I'm wary of introducing even more unexpected states to the backstack. And I'd really prefer not to have to try and test for the currentstate every time a navigate call is made.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use the below code before navigating to check whether the current destination is correct or not. This will make sure that the call happens from the current fragment only. This issue can be reproduced by clicking on two views simultaneously(Two items in a list).

```
if (findNavController().currentDestination?.id == R.id.currentFragment) {
        findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_current_next)
}
```

Comment: Best (only) way I've seen to deal with this so far. Problem can also occur if you press a button very quickly in succession (i.e., press on the button before the view has refreshed). Annoying that the Navigation library is so finnicky and easily gets "out" of it's fragment.

Comment: That works but you need to find why the function is called more than once. In my case I was registering an observer each time the fragment was restarted and it was never unregistered, so it was accumulating calls over time.

Comment: Is there a way to get the R.id.currentFragment?

Comment: What if we need to pass args?

Comment: @JachumbelechaoUntoMantekilla for you the `currentDestionation.id` also didn't match any `R.id`? For me it's in an entire different range: `2131230790` and `1000066`

Answer (score 5):

Okay, let me explain you this exception was pass because we are calling an action from a fragment(destination) which is not the current destination on the stack.

i.e
you're calling an action

```
R.id.action_aFragment_to_bFragment
```

from fragmentA but in navController current destination is other that fragmentA. That's why navController through that exception:

```
navigation destination com.xxx.yyy:id/action_aFragment_to_bFragment is unknown to this NavController
```

you can check the current destination before navigate. like

```
 Toast.makeText(context,view?.findNavController()?.currentDestination?.label,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
```

That will show you the current destination and i'm sure that's will be some other destination.

This will happens when we replace a fragment other than actions(like via old methods not with navigation) or we popUp that fragment before calling an action.

If that will be the case then you have to use **Global Action** because they don't care what current destination is.

Comment: I know why the exception is being called. And popping a Toast doesn't really help me, because this is production code (with a few users among thousands having this error), and as I said, I'm unable to recreate this on any device I own. If I could, I'd have solved this. There's also no navigation in this app implemented outside of the Navigation framework - that was the point of doing the rewrite which now has seen this problem pop up.

Comment: toast is just for clarification... i said because many people have that issue i describe above including me. Well if that is not the case then it's a bug in library.You know this lib is still in beta state.

Comment: i'm using these two libs and i did not get any error.    implementation 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:1.0.0-beta01'
    implementation 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:1.0.0-beta01'

Comment: Some people face that issue becasue they're using old version of library.

Comment: about the old version thing. a year later. v2.2.1 and I'm battling this non sense.