# Navigation safeArgs fails to navigate after back from dialog

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation-drawer, android-dialogfragment, android-safe-args

I'm getting `Illegal argumentException: Navigation action/destination pkgname:id/action_nav_home_to_dialog cannot be found from the current destination Destination(pkgname:id/dialog)` when navigate from HomeFragment to other fragment using safeArgs directions.
Even though Button in HomeFragment clicked,the current destination is pkgname:id/dialog.

should I check if the current destination is HomeFragment when navigate from HomeFragment to other Fragment every time ?
should I write some code on the dialog close?

In my investigation, it seems not happen after closing normal fragment.

## Ways to reproduce

1. create new  "Navigation Drawer Activity" project.
2. add classpath to dependencies of top level gradle file

```
def nav_version = "2.3.1"
classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$nav_version"
```

3. add apply plugin line to module level gradle file

```
apply plugin: "androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin"
```

4.create dialog fragment file

```
package pkgname.ui

import android.app.Dialog
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog
import androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment
class MyDialog : DialogFragment() {
  override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
      return AlertDialog.Builder(requireActivity())
          .setMessage("hello").create()
  }
}
```

5. add dialog to mobile_navigation.xml and action from home to dialog

```
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_home"
        android:name="pkgname.ui.home.HomeFragment"
        android:label="@string/menu_home"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_nav_home_to_dialog"
            app:destination="@id/dialog" />
    </fragment>
    <dialog
        android:id="@+id/dialog"
        android:name="pkgname.ui.MyDialog" />
```

6.add button to gragment_home.xml

```
   <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/showDialog"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="show dialog"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
 />
```

7. add click action to onCreateView of HomeFragment

```
 val showDialog: Button = root.findViewById(R.id.showDialog)
        showDialog.setOnClickListener { findNavController().navigate(HomeFragmentDirections.actionNavHomeToDialog()) }
```

8. Run app
9. tap "show dialog" button again and again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried your code. It was working fine. The dialog shows and dismiss as expected until I double clicked on the "SHOW DIALOG" button.The app started to crash when double clicked on the button.
In my case the error shown in the logcat was,

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: navigation destination com.xxx.navigationdraweractivity:id/action_nav_home_to_dialog is unknown to this NavController

As you asked in your question checking for the current destination solved the problem for me.

Change the code of button click in your HomeFragment like this,

```
showDialog.setOnClickListener {
  if (findNavController().currentDestination?.id == R.id.nav_home){
      findNavController().navigate(HomeFragmentDirections.actionNavHomeToDialog())
     }
}
```

The solution is from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/56168225/14698807

Comment: Thank you! I didn't see that message topic in this site is another matter. XD
This seems like a problem that libraries should address.