# Double click on view (recycler item) causes IllegalArgumentException: navigation destination is unknown to this NavController

Tags: android, navigation, android-jetpack, android-architecture-navigation

I am using navigation component in the project which I am currently working on. The problem is that when I click two items at the same time, that causes `findNavController.navigate()` to be called twice. So it throws `IllegalArgumentException: navigation destination is unknown to this NavController`. I think it goes to destination, then tries to trigger second time in that destination which doesn't have target destination. Destinationception...

Is there a way to check if current fragment has given destination or not?

Right now I've fixed the problem with below code but it doesn't look right.

```
fun NavController.navigateSafe(direction: NavDirections) {
    try {
        navigate(direction)
    } catch (exception: IllegalArgumentException) {
        Log.e("NavigationExtensions", exception.message.orEmpty())
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Thanks to [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51060762/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-navigation-destination-xxx-is-unknown-to-thi) that @Md.Asaduzzaman shares helped me.
Solution is;

```
fun NavController.navigateSafe(direction: NavDirections) {
    currentDestination?.getAction(direction.actionId)?.let { navigate(direction) }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: navigation destination xxx is unknown to this NavController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51060762/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-navigation-destination-xxx-is-unknown-to-thi)