# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: navigation destination {actionId} is unknown to this NavController when Activity is recreated?

Tags: android, android-fragments, illegalargumentexception, android-architecture-navigation, android-navigation

I am coming from reading all the answers in [IllegalArgumentException: navigation destination xxx is unknown to this NavController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51060762/illegalargumentexception-navigation-destination-xxx-is-unknown-to-this-navcontr) with no luck. I am getting this when the activity is recreated from either a manual recreate() call or coming back from a process death.

I have an `Activity` that changes its `Fragments` using `Navigation`.
Fragment A has a FAB that navigates to Fragment B when clicked.

```
   floatingActionButton = view.findViewById<FloatingActionButton>(R.id.floating_action_button).apply {
       setOnClickListener {
           findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_fragmentA_to_fragmentB,
              null,
              null,
              FragmentNavigatorExtras(this to "shared_element_container"))
       }
   }
```

Works fine but when the FAB is clicked after the activity is recreated I get a crash.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had accidentally given the same id to a nested graph and a fragment.