# App restarts when resuming from background after some time

Tags: android, navigation

The scenario is when the app is on Fragment A and then kept the app in the background for some time. After resuming from the background the initial state of the app is in Fragment A but then suddenly app restarts from startDestination in the navigation component causing the below crash.

```
 Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Navigation action/destination com.app.gulfcraftv2:id/action_splashFragment_to_nav_home cannot be found from the current destination Destination(com.app.gulfcraftv2:id/companyFragment) class=com.precise.gulfcraft.ui.companydetail.CompanyDetailFragment
   at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.kt:1540)
   at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.kt:1472)
   at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.kt:1930)
   at com.precise.gulfcraft.ui.splash.SplashFragment.onCreate$lambda-6(SplashFragment.kt:75)
   at com.precise.gulfcraft.ui.splash.SplashFragment.lambda$Aso8YI02DbFhfWptH-qrBUU0ulU()
   at com.precise.gulfcraft.ui.splash.-$$Lambda$SplashFragment$Aso8YI02DbFhfWptH-qrBUU0ulU.run(:2)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7562)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
```

Note - The launch mode used is singleTop

The crash is happening in the below section.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    try {
        Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
            findNavController().navigate(SplashFragmentDirections.actionSplashFragmentToNavHome())
        }, 3000)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this is the answer to the question you are already in the same fragment https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51060762/illegalargumentexception-navigation-destination-xxx-is-unknown-to-this-navcontr#answer-53737537

Comment: @RobinHood Actually the crash is happening due to the app restart.

Comment: before loading the fragment check the current destination. You don't need to load again and again <code>currentDestination?.getAction(resId) != null || currentDestination?.id != resId</code>

Comment: can you see your code logic

Comment: Which logic do you want to see?

Comment: logic relevant to your question

Comment: I added it to the question

Answer (score 0):

check first if this is your current destination with following function

```
fun navigate(destination: NavDirections) = with(findNavController()) {
    currentDestination?.getAction(destination.actionId)
        ?.let { navigate(destination) }
}
```