# how to retrieve the object data from gettag of edittext

Tags: android, android-edittext

I don't get how to get the object value after setting the tag with a key for an edittext.

```
edittext.settag("uniqkey",new Project(projectname, projectid, String.valueOf(s), peojectdesc, projecttype));
```

How to retrieve using `getTag` of edittext?

Comment: What's the error apart from **missing `)` at the end**?

Comment: @Rohit sorrry forgot to add bracket
Actually its not the error how to retrieve it

Comment: @stackmarianny: please see if my answer helps you

Comment: Added missing `)` as per confirmation in comment.

Answer (score 1):

There is no overload of method `setTag` which would accept String as the first parameter. See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View

Use either of below

```
edittext.settag(new Project(projectname, projectid, String.valueOf(s), peojectdesc, projecttype));
```

or

```
edittext.settag(0, new Project(projectname, projectid, String.valueOf(s), peojectdesc, projecttype)); // first parmeter could be any int value
```

To fetch use either of below as per set method used

```
Project project  = (Project)edittext.gettag();
```

or

```
Project project  = (Project)edittext.gettag(0); // use the key used for setting the tag
```

**Edit**

To get `projectname` do this after fetching tag

```
String projectName = project.projectname; // If its a public property
```

or

```
String projectName = project.getProjectName(); // If you have getter setter
```

if none is true, create a getter method for it in the POJO.

Comment: Then how to get individual data from project

Comment: You can achieve exactly what you want to achieve using int key rather than a string key. there is no difference.

Comment: its not about the key the doubt is hot to print the gettag object

Comment: printing is a different matter. You can override `toString` in the POJO. Int this method print every property of this POJO you want to print. Then use it to print it. Like `project.toString()`

Comment: one more doubt how to take the projectname in this case 
Project project  = (Project)edittext.gettag(0);

Comment: setting tag showing error 
IllegalArgumentException: The key must be an application-specific resource id.

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2859574/the-key-must-be-an-application-specific-resource-id